# Processing large number of html files to extract data best storage mechanism for flat text files

Tags: database, file, data-mining, data-manipulation

I index the html of specific websites and to do so pull it down to disk so I have a quite a few flat files of html. I then take the html and extract data from it and generate json files which contain the data I need.

I end up with a structure something like this

/pages/website.com/index_date/sectionofsite/afile.html
/pages/website.com/index_date/sectionofsite/afile.json

I need to keep the original html as I might need to reprocess it to produce the json. The problem now is that I have gigs and gigs of flat html files.

I can compress the html files no problem but sometimes I need to reprocess everything to extract another value or fix a bug. If I compress the html then the problem is if I re-processed a set of files I would need to

1. unzip the html
2. extract data and generate json.
3. compress the html back to zip.

The reality is that is super slow when you have tons and tons of files. I looked at mongodb (and its WiredTiger Storage Engine with zlib compression) as a possible solution for storing the html as its essentially text and not binary but mongo db kept crashing with lots of plain html text. I think the PHP Library is a big buggy.

I need a way other than the file system to store plain text files but have a way to access them fast. It would be preferable if the storage mechanism also compressed the plain text files. Curious if anyone has run into a similar problem and how they solved it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since HTML and JSON compress very well, you should store them compressed.

Rather than zip, use gzip. Because zip is an *archiver*, while gzip compresses one stream only. *Every* programming language has a function to read and write gzip files as if they weren't compressed. E.g. in python, you simply use `gzip.open` instead of `open`, or in Java you wrap it with a `GZipInputStream`.

Then you may want to look into *embedded* databases. Don't use MongoDB, because it is slow. Use e.g. one SQLite file per site to store the compressed data. Using a server (i.e. PostgreSQL or MongoDB) is only beneficial if you have multiple processes working on the same files. Unless you need this concurrency, embedded databases are much faster (because they don't transmit the data). If you don't need any of the SQL features, libraries such as BerkeleyDB are even smaller.

But in the end, your filesystem is also a database. Not a particularly bad one, but not designed for millions of entries and only supporting only name->data lookups. But most file systems use blocks for storing, so any file will use a multiple of e.g. 8kb of disk, even if your data is much smaller. It's these situations where embedded databases help. They also use blocks, but you can configure the block size to be smaller to reduce waste.